# css isnt working outside localhost, i can access the page via ip adress (x.x.x.x), it loads but without style using codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, wamp

Im using codeigniter and wamp. My assets carpet is outside codeigniter´s app carpet. Every file inside assets works fine in local host. When I try to access the side outside localhost using my ip adress, which is 172.16.19.81, the site loads but without style and without imgaes. What coul be the problem ?? thanks.

Comment: Post the code for the links to your stylesheets.

Comment: Checked your console to see if the stylesheets are being loaded?

Comment: are the stylesheets and images inside a publicly accessible folder?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used codeigniter but for example in wordpress I have to specify the host name in the admin panel so it loads the resources, for example if I put localhost it will only load the resources when I access it through localhost but if I change it to my ip address it works when accessing from the outside